# New record fails in Collector with particular FGDB relationship topology

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, arcgis-collector

*This is lifted from my [GeoNet post](https://community.esri.com/t5/geodatabase-questions/new-record-fails-in-collector-w-specific-realtionship/m-p/864960) asking the same question.*

I have FGDB that I am trying to build out for in-the-field surveys through AGO and Collector. Below is a mock diagram of the tables that I am having trouble. FeatureLayer1 is existing features. FeatureLayer2 is newly created features.These are simple, unattributed relationships.

[image]

In Pro: If I create a new feature in FeatureLayer2 and then a new record for SharedTable1, everything is saved without issue. If I select a feature in FeatureLayer1 and create a record in Table1 and then a SharedTable1 record, everything is saved without issue. I can even upload the edits done in Pro to AGO and they appear in Collector as expected.

In Collector: If I create a new feature in FeatureLayer2 and then a new record for SharedTable1, when I tell it to submit the record it says, "1 or more attributes failed to submit". If I select a feature in FeatureLayer1 and create a record in Table1 and then a SharedTable1 record, when I tell it to submit the record it says, "1 or more attributes failed to submit".

If I recreate the relationships, like below. All record creation is submitted and works as expected in both Pro and Collector.

[image]

Am I forgetting something rather obvious about relationship integrity in the first relationship design; is Pro ignoring something that Collector is catching? Or is there a caveat about using FGDB or Collector with this design?

Also, is there a log for Collector, either in the app or AGO that could help diagnose this problem? "1 or more attributes failed to submit" is an extremely unhelpful error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per a response from ESRI support:

ArcGIS Online does not support the use of UUID/GUIDs as a primary key for records.

For RDBMS in ArcSDE, UUIDs can be used but for Portal/AGO you must use a composite key or OIDs